# the method getController() is undefined for the type MapView

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i want to detect the user location by google maps and follow a google tutorial  but there is error 
in the method(getController) in line 6 , the error details the method getController()  is undefined for the type MapView

```
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ogenia);

    MapView view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    final MapController control = view.getController();
    LocationManager Manager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            control.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int) location.getLatitude(),
                    (int) location.getLongitude()));
        }
    };

    Manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            listener);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There are two Maps APIs for Android.

One is Maps V1. Its classes are in the `com.google.android.maps` package. Maps V1 has been deprecated and should not be used for new apps.

The other is Maps V2. Its classes are in the `com.google.android.gms.maps` package.

You are attempting to blend both. **This will not work**.

I would recommend that you spend some time reading [the documentation for Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) and focusing on that, removing all references to Maps V1 classes from your code.

Comment: thanks in advance but how me to blend the two in the code , what is in the code meant that ??

Comment: i read the documentation many times :)but no reply for problem